# Personal contacts displaying in business members directory

Tags: wordpress, civicrm.settings.php

A website for a client runs CiviCRM on Wordpress.

Part of their membership site contains a membership directory so the public can see their registered/active members.

The members are essentially businesses. In CiviCRM we have people setup as individuals and businesses as organisations, with a relationship between them. Those relationships may be staff, directors or owners.

The issue we have is the membership directory is also showing people who have relationships with those organisations (in the list) instead of just the business.

Question is, what setting do we need to change to fix this?

Comment: What plugin (or other method) are you using to display the membership directory?  Or is this done using profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings for this particular membership type to see if the membership is extended to related contacts.

[image]